# Formato cursiva o negrita por consola

Tags: java

Buenas a todos. He estado buscando como darle formato de texto a un número y no he encontrado nada claro.

La idea era buscar el valor mayor y menor de la matriz y después de encontrarlos, darle el formato de negrita.

```
int mayor = matriz[0][0];
int menor = matriz[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++){
            if(matriz[i][j] < menor)
                menor = matriz[i][j];
            else if (matriz[i][j] > mayor)
                mayor = matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Gracias de antemano.

Buenas tardes.

Comment: No puede imprimir en negrita con Java en consola `System.out`

Comment: Pfua... Gracias. Estoy aprendiendo y las dudas las pregunto aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto realmente depende de qué tipo de consola se está utilizando. Para IDE como Netbeans y Eclipse, no estoy seguro de si puede afectar la fuente. Pero para la mayoría de las terminales, funciona el siguiente personaje de escape:

```
String textoEnNegrita = "Java_Prof_Level";

System.out.print("\033[0;1m" + textoEnNegrita);
```

La secuencia ANSI `"\033[0;1m"` antes de el string lo tendría que poner en negrita

Comment: Buena respuesta. Quizás estaría bueno que agregues alguna otra secuencia de escape ANSI, o algún enlace para quien le interese